# How to use the audio output in a DE10 Standard board using c?

Tags: c, fpga

I just want to play a simple tone when a variable is set to true, I can't find any examples of this using c.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know its broad but thats because any way of doing it using c should be fine.

Board Manual: https://ftp.intel.com/Public/Pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/18.1/Computer_Systems/DE10-Standard/DE10-Standard_Computer_NiosII.pdf

Comment: This question is much broader than you probably think.

Comment: For a start, can you provide a link to the information about the board?